# How to hide columns in ssrs report builder based on startdate and enddate parameters?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am new to SSRS. I have created a report with the following format.

[image]

I want to hide months columns based on startdate and enddate parameters. How can I achieve this? Suppose user selects date from July to Aug then Jun2014 should be hidden.

Any Ideas? Please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tablix is of the [matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149(v=sql.105).aspx) variant, then the easiest way would be to ensure that your dataset doesn't contain any data outside the date range the user has selected. If its not then definitely read up about matrix style reports and convert it!